# How to enforce before() to complete before executing tests in Mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am a newbie to the JavaScript ecosystem. I am trying to write couple of API tests for my REST APIs using Mocha/Chai. My requirement is that I have to cleanup my database before running each test cases. So, I wrote the following code in a file called *dbCleanup.js*

```
var config = require("config.json");
const pg = require('pg');

var connectionString = config.pgConnectionString
console.log("DB Connection String: ", connectionString)

function dbCleanup() {

    var dbTables = ["projects", "employees"];

    var pgClient = new pg.Client(connectionString);

    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pg.connect(connectionString, (err, pgClient, done) => {
            if (err) {
                done();
                console.log(err);
                reject();
            }

            for (i = 0; i < dbTables.length; i++) {
                query = "TRUNCATE " + dbTables[i] + " CASCADE;"
                pgClient.query(query, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        done();
                        console.error('error running query', err);
                        reject();
                    }
                    resolve();
                });
            }
        });
    });

    pgClient.end()

    return promise;
}

exports.dbCleanup = dbCleanup;
```

I have another file called *globalBefore.js* where I have the following code:

```
var dbCleanup = require('./dbCleanup.js').dbCleanup;

function _beforeClean(done) {
    try {
        dbCleanup()
            .then(done)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

exports.beforeCleanup = _beforeClean;
```

Now in my Mocha *test.js* file, I try to call the database cleanup function as follows:

```
var request = require("request");
var rp = require("request-promise");
var config = require("../config.json");
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var data = require("./data.json");

var globalBefore = require("../globalBefore.js");


describe("POST /employees/", function () {

    console.log("clearing db tables...")
    before(globalBefore.beforeCleanup, function (done) {
        done();
    });

    beforeEach(function (done) {
    ... do some business logic related work here ...
    });


    it.only('Try create an employee', function (done) {
    ... API call to create an employee and use Chai assertions to validate ...
    });
});
```

The problem I am facing is, Mocha goes ahead with running my tests even before the dbCleanup() function completes. This causes my DB to go kaput and I encounter undesired behavior.

Can anyone from the SO community please help? I tried various options I could find in the web, but not able to fix the issue. As shown in the code fragment, I hoped that using a Promise should have solved the problem

To be more generic, how do I enforce the instructions inside a **before** clause to complete before Mocha runs the **it** clauses for the tests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `before` the wrong way. Try this instead:

```
before(function (done) {
    globalBefore.beforeCleanup(done);
});
```

or

```
before(globalBefore.beforeCleanup);
```

And in `globalBefore.js`:

```
var dbCleanup = require('./dbCleanup.js').dbCleanup;

function _beforeClean(done) {
    dbCleanup().then(done).catch(done);
}

exports.beforeCleanup = _beforeClean;
```

**EXAMPLE (I only changed dbCleanup.js to use a another promise)**

`dbCleanup.js`

```
function dbCleanup() {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
    });

}

exports.dbCleanup = dbCleanup;
```

`globalBefore.js`

```
var dbCleanup = require('./dbCleanup.js').dbCleanup;

function _beforeClean(done) {
    dbCleanup().then(done).catch(done);
}

exports.beforeCleanup = _beforeClean;
```

`index.js`

```
var globalBefore = require("../globalBefore.js");

describe("POST /employees/", function () {

    this.timeout(5000); // because the promise take 2000ms

    console.log("clearing db tables...")
    before(function (done) {
        console.log('before calling beforeCleanup');
        globalBefore.beforeCleanup(function () {
            console.log('after calling beforeCleanup');
            done(); // done cleaning db
        });
    });

    /* Without the console.logs
    console.log("clearing db tables...");
    before(globalBefore.beforeCleanup)
    */

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        // ... do some business logic related work here ...
        console.log('beforeEach');
        done();
    });


    it.only('Try create an employee', function (done) {
        // ... API call to create an employee and use Chai assertions to validate ...
        console.log('it');
        done();
    });
});
```

**OUTPUT**

```
clearing db tables...

  POST /employees/
before calling beforeCleanup
after calling beforeCleanup
beforeEach
it
    √ Try create an employee


  1 passing (2s)
```

https://mochajs.org/#hooks

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I tried both the options and I am running into the same problem. My tests starts running even before the dbCleanup() function completes. I am now wondering if my cleanup function and the way I am using Promises is actually doing its part or not :-(

Comment: You also have an error with the `try/catch`, for promises, you need to use `Promise.catch`. I changed that and added a working example.

Comment: Thank You so much @luisenrike for the detailing out the solution. This worked for me.